# Parsing large text files and subjecting retrieved information to regex

Tags: perl

My input file contains the following information in this manner

```
>V063O:34:49 length=314
GAGATGACTCCCAGGGGGGGGGGATGAAACCCAGACCTGGCACCATGGGATCAGCCATTC
CATCTTGACCAAAGGGGGGGGGGAAAGAAAGTGTAATTAATAAAGTACAGTGGCAGAGAG
AGTTCAAATAGTTGCGAGTCTACTCTGGAGGTTGCTGTTGTGCTAAGCTTCAGGTTATAC
CTTGACCCTACCATACCCCCCAAACCAGGACAATTCCAAGCCCAAATCCGTAAAAGAAAC
ACCTAAGGCAATATATAAGATTCTACAGGTCATACATCTAGACTACTTACTAACAATCCG
TAACAACCTCAGAT
>V063O:35:44 length=104
GCTCTTTTTTTTTTTAGCAAAAACCGTTAGCCAATCCCTACCCAACCCCTGGCACCTGGG
GGGGGGTGCCCGAGCGCCGGTGGGAGAACGGAGGAAACGCACTC
```

The sequences (string of data below ID and length=) will be subjected to the following regex

```
 #Search sequence for a combination of 2 values of ACGT that are repeated at least 10 times
        my $regex1 = qr/( ([ACGT]{2}) \2{9,} )/x;
    #Search sequence for a combination of 3 values of ACGT that are repeated at least 7 times
        my $regex2 = qr/( ([ACGT]{3}) \2{6,} )/x;
    #Search sequence for a combination of 4 values of ACGT that are repeated at least 7 times
        my $regex3 = qr/( ([ACGT]{4}) \2{6,} )/x;
for my $regex ($regex1, $regex2, $regex3) {
    next unless $seq1 =~ $regex;
    printf "Matched %s exactly %d times\n", $2, length($1)/length($2);
    printf "Length of sequence: $number \n";
}
```

This currently returns the results from a sample text file containing only a single sequence to the command line

I need to be able to print the following elements found either within the file and the regex above to a single file for each sequence in the text file (so one file for all sequences found within the text file).

```
ID (example: V0630:34:49) , The elements that are repeating (example; GCT), the number of repeats (example; 13), and the length of the entire sequence.
```

Conditions are that BioPerl is not an option (user is not Perl-savvy, so this is meant to be as easy for the end user as possible without having to download modules) and that the input files are very large in nature (300MBs or more).

What would be the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: Hey, where'd you get that genome from? It looks suspiciously like mine :-)

Comment: User is not Perl-savvy, so you're giving the user regular expressions? lol.

Comment: Well, I'm hoping the end-user just has to point to the input file and run the script with no fiddling involved. It should be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it looks like this may be homework. Are you meant to be solving this problem on your own?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @regexes = (
  qr/( ([ACGT]{2}) \2{9,} )/x,
  qr/( ([ACGT]{3}) \2{6,} )/x,
  qr/( ([ACGT]{4}) \2{6,} )/x,
);

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt';

my $seq;
my $id;

while (<$fh>) {

  if (/^>(\S+)/) {
    process_sequence($id, $seq) if $seq;
    $id = $1;
    $seq = ''
  }
  else {
    chomp;
    $seq .= $_;
  }
}
process_sequence($id, $seq) if $seq;

sub process_sequence {
  my ($id, $seq) = @_;
  for my $regex (@regexes) {
      next unless $seq =~ $regex;
      printf "Sequence ID %s matched %s exactly %d times\n", $id, $2, length($1)/length($2);
      printf "Length of sequence: %s \n", length $seq;
      print "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a project, but we are encouraged to seek out help both within our class and external sources. We've not really covered too much, and have yet to touch on conditionals, loops, hashes (such as the if (/^>(\S+)/) - we've not even looked at that!) I completely understand your concern.

Comment: OK. Are you happy with this answer?

Comment: The regular expression `/^>(\S+)/` checks whether the line starts with a right angle bracket followed by a number of non-space characters and, if so, captures those non-space characters and makes them available as `$1`.

Comment: I am happy in that it allows me to analyze the program and gives me a basis in understanding how the information is processed and stored. It gives me an excellent starting point! I still have to go through and add comments explaining what each line does, which I will do myself. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Why /((p){2}\2{9,})/ instead of /((p{2}){10,})/ ?